# What is the package/object/request containing information in JSON format called when it's in transit from the browser to the server?

Tags: json, http, request

I'm not even sure what the correct wording is to ask this question. I don't mean what is it in the browser or what is it in the server. I mean what is it after it's been bundled up for transit? I'm guessing that it's probably the same whether it's JSON or something else, but what's it called?

Comment: Do you mean the [request body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages#body)?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be correct. I got tangled in plain language syntax where there is a request and a reply.

Comment: That link is very helpful